# remove in app purchase product as previous rejection from app

Tags: ios

Submitted a app to app store with a in app purchase product for the very first time, it got rejected few times, Now I just to submit an app without the in app purchase, as the in app purchase product is already waiting for review, if I submit a new binary, the product will go into review again I guess.

Since itune connect changed ui, I can't find where I can edit the version that is waiting to submit. What should I do to just submit app without in app purchase product.